# is it possible to send Refresh Commands from a server to a client that has no STATIC IP on c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming, windows-networking

so  here is my goal 
ther's this applications which we wrote (we being me and my team),and then we decided that the app needs some sort of online support.
the application is written in c# and uses SQL as db,and the app has Dongles.
im trying to develop online and offline ticket methods,however the problem showed up when i realized the chat has to be refreshed...i.e the message that the admin panel sends to the user has to somehow tell the user to refresh the ui and get the data from the online server itself...
if the client had static ip address,that would have worked fine,but with no static ip address the only solution i can think of is to write a timer in every client and tell it to refresh the data every x seconds,which isnt a good method in my opinion.
so
TLDR : is there a way to refresh the data without writing timers?like can the server access the client without that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use longpooling strategy.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling

Or if you're using only sql server - you can use SQL Server Notification Services

Also you can use SqlDependency if you use LINQ to SQL. The simpliest way described there dunnry.com/blog/UsingSQLDependencyObjectsWithLINQ.aspx

Comment: thank you for the answer,just 1 more thing<br>is the Notification service thingy in sql only about sending mails and Text messages ? does it not provide a unique identifier or somethin that can work with the Client side app?like can it tell the client to refresh when it has to be refreshed?sry but im askin that before reading the whole thing we're in a rush here :s

Comment: also one more thing?... we used Linq to Sql here,i asked around and ive been told that the services can only be used with ADO and we cant use that cuz we used linq :s

Comment: So I advice you to use SqlDependency. The simpliest way described there http://dunnry.com/blog/UsingSQLDependencyObjectsWithLINQ.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> TLDR : is there a way to refresh the data without writing timers?like can the server access the client without that?

No, the server can't initiate a connection to a client. The client can be behind a firewall or a NAT for example. You can have the client poll for updates, or you can have an open connection (initiated by the client) where the server can notify of updates.